# Connecting selected item on combobox to a row in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

When a item is pressed in the combobox i want to call the csv and retrive the row which matches when the item clicked in the combobox

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
 def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    sales=pd.read_csv ("C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Info/Topholdings/csv/Master_table.csv")
    sales_article = sales ["Company"] .dropna()
    sales_list = sales_article.values.tolist()
    self.Fundwise = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.Fundwise.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(308, 141, 141, 61))
    self.Fundwise.setObjectName("sales_list")
    self.Fundwise.addItems(arr_list)
```

In the above code I call the csv file and select the first column as list which is displayed in the combobox ,but when the user clicks one of the items in the combobox how to call the selected strings row

Comment: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#activated-1

Comment: Yes i got it  ` self.Fundwise.activated[str].connect(self.selected)` and then I called the function selected which matches the string and calls the paticular row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
     #....
     self.Fundwise.activated.connect(self._set_fundwise)

def _set_fundwise(self):
    _data = self.Fundwise.currentData()
    if _data:
       #call selected strings
```